# Numpy meshgrid 2d-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mesh

I want to create a meshgrid and I only have one 2-dimensional array.

I want to create this:

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4])
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b))
## mesh = 
## array([[[1, 2],
##    [1, 2]],
##
##   [[3, 3],
##    [4, 4]]])
```

but the input is one array containing a and b, like this:

```
ab = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(ab))
## mesh = 
## array([[[1, 2],
##    [1, 2]],
##
##   [[3, 3],
##    [4, 4]]])
```

Is their a way to archive that even with 3 or 4 arrays packed in one big one like this:

```
abcd = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can unpack `abcd` and pass to `messgrid`:

```
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(*abcd))
```